# DataTables sort differently asc/desc

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatable

I'm using the [DataTables](http://datatables.net) library, with hierarchical data. What I wish to do is to have the groups always appear in the same order, and have the column sorts apply only within groups.

For example, with the following table:

```
GROUP     FOOD
===================
fruit     banana
fruit     pear
fruit     apple
meat      steak
meat      chicken
meat      pork
vegetable zucchini
vegetable broccoli
vegetable tomato
```

When the user clicks the "food" column, it should sort ascending as follows:

```
GROUP     FOOD ▲
===================
fruit     apple
fruit     banana
fruit     pear
meat      chicken
meat      pork
meat      steak
vegetable broccoli
vegetable tomato
vegetable zucchini
```

When the user clicks the "food" column again, it should sort descending as follows:

```
GROUP     FOOD ▼
===================
fruit     pear
fruit     banana
fruit     apple
meat      steak
meat      pork
meat      chicken
vegetable zucchini
vegetable tomato
vegetable broccoli
```

However, the actual behavior is that it also inverts the ordering of the groups:

```
GROUP     FOOD ▼
===================
vegetable zucchini
vegetable tomato
vegetable broccoli
meat      steak
meat      pork
meat      chicken
fruit     pear
fruit     banana
fruit     apple
```

[This example](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html) shows how to write a custom sort function; however, there's no way of knowing from within the function if the column is being sorted ASC or DESC. **What is the best way to specify a different sort function for ASC vs. DESC order on a given column?**

Comment: possible to get a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Usually with these types of tables you can specify a sorting function, and toggling the return value from 1 to -1 will change the sort. For example:

```
items.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a < b) { return 1; }
    else if (a === b) { return 0; }
    else { return -1; }
});
```

sorts in one direction, and

```
items.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a < b) { return -1; }
    else if (a === b) { return 0; }
    else { return 1; }
});
```

Sorts in the other.

Comment: This comment is irrelevant for DataTables. While I can easily implement ascending or descending sort, what I'm looking for is how DataTables exposes which sort is active on a given column.

Comment: can you store a variable in your sort function or out of scope which will hold the current sort type?

Comment: The existence of such a variable is what I'm looking for in this question :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I managed to find the location of the current sort direction, under `column.context[0].aaSorting[0][1]`. The `aaSorting` variable is an array of arrays, the bottom level of which contains the current sort column (as an integer) and sort direction (as a string; `asc` or `desc`).

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['grouped-item'] = function(settings, col){
    var column = this.api().column(col);
    var sortOrder = column.context[0].aaSorting[0][1];
    return column.data().sort(function(a,b){
        // ...
    }).map( function ( x, i ) {
        // ...
    } );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my other answer is more in line with the original question, I'll leave it, but it turns out I was asking the wrong question. DataTables allows you to force sort by a particular column before sorting by others.

- [orderFixed option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed)